# C# Changing values between 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to change values between two arrays, but im not getting get that right.

This is what I've done so far
I cant show the total of the first array and i cant make any swap at the second array

```
public static void exe4()
        {
            int[,] matriz1 = new int[,] { { -2, 3, 4, 11, -8 }, { -1, 0, -12, -6, 9 }, { 23, 4, 6, 8, -3 } };
            int[,] matriz2 = new int[,] { { 2, 3, 8 }, { -2, -4, -5 }, { 0, 8, -14 }, { 3, 5, 6 }, { -9, -8, -1 } };
        int troca1 = 0;
        int troca2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                troca1 = matriz1[i, j];
                matriz1[1, 0] = matriz2[0, 2];
                matriz1[1, 1] = matriz2[1, 2];
                matriz1[1, 4] = matriz2[4, 1];

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
           
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                troca2 = matriz2[i, j];
                matriz2[0, 2] = matriz1[1, 0];
                matriz2[1, 2] = matriz1[1, 1];
                matriz2[4, 2] = matriz1[1, 4];
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
            
        
        Console.WriteLine("\nApós a troca dos valores:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Matriz1:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", matriz1[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nMatriz2:\n");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", matriz2[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

That's how it's supposed to be:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Sure, let me see what you've tried first.

Comment: You generally get the same amount of effort in the answers you receive as you put into the question.  In this case, your question doesn't contain any indication you've tried *anything at all*, so I'm not sure how much effort you can expect from people helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Analyzing your solution

It sounds like you're only interested in swapping very few and specific values in those matrices, so for-loops seem unnecessary as you already know the positions in the matrices you want to swap.

Apart from that I noticed that your for-loops only goes from 0 to 2 (`for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`) but your matrices have a length of 4 in one dimension, so the loops never reach the ends.

#### An alternative solution

If you just want to swap those specific values, you could do it like this:

```
int[,] matriz1 = new int[,]
{
    { -2, 3,   4, 11, -8 },
    { -1, 0, -12, -6,  9 },
    { 23, 4,   6,  8, -3 }
};
int[,] matriz2 = new int[,]
{
    {  2,  3,   8 },
    { -2, -4,  -5 },
    {  0,  8, -14 },
    {  3,  5,   6 },
    { -9, -8,  -1 }
};

int temporary;

// Swap A[1,0] with B[0,2]
temporary = matriz1[1,0];
matriz1[1,0] = matriz2[0,2];
matriz2[0,2] = temporary;

// Swap A[1,1] with B[1,2]
temporary = matriz1[1,0];
matriz1[1,1] = matriz2[1,2];
matriz2[1,2] = temporary;

// Swap A[1,4] with B[4,2]
temporary = matriz1[1,0];
matriz1[1,4] = matriz2[4,2];
matriz2[4,2] = temporary;
```

... or with a little helper function:

```
void Swap(int[,] matrixA, int row1, int col1, int[,] matrixB, int row2, int col2)
{
    var temp = matrixA[row1, col1];
    matrixA[row1, col1] = matrixB[row2, col2];
    matrixB[row2, col2] = temp;
}

// ...
Swap(matriz1, 1, 0, matriz2, 0, 2);
Swap(matriz1, 1, 1, matriz2, 1, 2);
Swap(matriz1, 1, 4, matriz2, 4, 2);
```